# Extjs:Set variable after ajax request

Tags: ajax, extjs

How I can set "price" variable after ajax call?
here the code:

```
                var price;
                var idProd = data.prodotto_id;

                var cb = function (o,s,r){

                    price = Ext.util.JSON.decode(r.responseText).price;
                    console.log(price);
                };
                    Ext.Ajax.request({
                        url : "index.php",
                        params : {
                            m : "Prodotti",
                            a : 'prod-price-byquantity',
                            idProd : idProd,
                            quantity: qta
                        },
                        callback : cb,
                        scope : this
                    });


                console.log(price);
```

In the last console.log(price) I see price as undefined

Answer (score 1):

That's because Ajax requests are asynchronous - your callback function will not be called immediately. Here's how it goes:

```
var price; // = undefined;
Ext.Ajax.request();
// The request is sent and the function immediately returns
console.log(price); // undefined
...
some time passes
...
// Finally the request finishes and your callback function is called;
price = Ext.util.JSON.decode(r.responseText).price;
console.log(price); // some new value
```

So you are getting the price variable **after** the ajax call has finished.

Comment: In my code, I get the variable content inside the callback function...  I suppose callback function is will be called after ajax response... what do you think about it?

Answer (score 1):

this work

```
fetchRow:function(params){
    var me = this;
    var v;
    this.fetchRowRequest(params,function(value){
        v = value;
    });
    return v;
}
fetchRowRequest: function(params,callback){
    var me = this;
    var record;
    Ext.Ajax.request({
        url: me.proxy.api.read,
        params: {filters:Ext.encode(params)},
        async:false,
        success: function(response){
             var response = Ext.decode(response.responseText);
             var row = response.rows[0];
             if(row){
                var record = Ext.create(me.model.prototype.modelName);
                record.set(row); 
             }else{
                record = false;
             }
             callback(record);
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score -1):

As you can see,"price" variable is assigned a value inside "cb" function so price is accessible only inside cb.You must use this.price="bla bla" so price will be available and modifiable globally inside your class/namespace.

Then you must use console.log(this.price); to output the price.

Comment: Not at all. The `price` variable is defined outside `cb` function and is perfectly accessible all around the given code snippet.